# How to generate payload using camelCase attributes with DRF serializers

Tags: json, django, django-rest-framework, serialization

So I need to consume an API that the JSON fields are all camelCase and I want to write them on my code as snake_case. How can I do this?

I want something like this:

```
serializer = MySerializer(data={'my_field': 'test'})
if serializer.is_valid():
  output_data = serializer.validated_data
  print(output_data)
  # {'myField': 'test'}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

djangorestframework-camel-case by Vitaly Babiy does exactly this: https://github.com/vbabiy/djangorestframework-camel-case
You have to just mention it in settings.py like this:

```py
REST_FRAMEWORK = {

    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'djangorestframework_camel_case.render.CamelCaseJSONRenderer',
        'djangorestframework_camel_case.render.CamelCaseBrowsableAPIRenderer',
        # Any other renders
    ),

    'DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES': (
        # If you use MultiPartFormParser or FormParser, we also have a camel case version
        'djangorestframework_camel_case.parser.CamelCaseFormParser',
        'djangorestframework_camel_case.parser.CamelCaseMultiPartParser',
        'djangorestframework_camel_case.parser.CamelCaseJSONParser',
        # Any other parsers
    ),
}
```

and it works, no need to change your serializers.

Comment: So django-rest-framework serializers don't support this and I would need to use `to_json` with the names I want instead of using their `ModelSerializer`? That's too bad, I don't really want to include an extra library just to do this.